# iOS testflight sdk arm7 architecture issue

Tags: ios, cocoapods, testflight

I have added test flight sdk to my project and after archive it I got this error:

```
ld: warning: ignoring file Include/libapps-on-maps-sim.a, file was built for archive which is not the architecture being linked (armv7): Include/libapps-on-maps-sim.a
Undefined symbols for architecture armv7:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_TestFlight", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in MTAppDelegate.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture armv7
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

How can I change architecture for this file? I have architecture settings for my project and for pods `$(ARCHS_STANDARD)`